# sharing Data between several websites

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

If i had two different application running under the same solution but using different Databases can i share User credentials between those applications ?? any solution other Than The SSO and the Machine key in the `web.config` where the authentication is based on the default Asp.net Database ( i guess it's called the membership database )

if their is a solution could You please help

Comment: hehe thank for the edit i'm new in stackoverflow i don't know how to post a comment their is so many strict laws " " to how to post them

Comment: I don't want to sound like a grammar nazi but it is not "their" it is "there".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are it two seperate IIS websites? And what are the real requirements you have? Just share some variables or move data from one application to another?

I'd think you'd probably better look into creating a service layer to receive and send information between sites. This way you can eventually seperate the two applications on different web front ends without problems.

This service layer can be implemented using different techniques like XML Web Services, WCF, or maybe you could look at the new ASP.NET Web API http://www.asp.net/web-api

---

edit:

Ok clear from the comments I got some more info: 
Imho you could do two things: schedule a synchronisation using some mechanism (could be xml export / import) every day or so. But if you'd want realtime SSO, you could simply create a service on the webserver connected to the authentication database where the only functionality is to authenticate users. Something like a: bool validatecredentials(string username, string passwordHash). If you're not talking about thousands of authentication requests this will perform quite good using standard WCF or some other service technology. If you are talking about larger systems or implementations you should look at Claims based authentication, .NET has a technique called WIF to implement that. It works using a seperate STS (Security Token Service) to issue tokens with claims who a user is and what he is allowed to do, etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer i guess i'll try to use an XML file to pass user data between those sites

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on you're exact requirements? If you are going to use that xml file a lot you might get into problems with read/write locking, etc. But if you schedule an import / export for some data it might work just fine!

Comment: i want to pass user credentials like the id and the username i want to do an SSO environment but my problem is the to application have their own database they don't share a one common database is their a solution to my problem ???

Comment: See my edit, please mark as answer if it helps you for your solution